# Trace listener ignores traceOutputOptions="DateTime"

Tags: .net, app-config, trace

I'm configuring tracing in the project and cannot add date or timestamp to the traces. It seems that `traceOutputOptions` is just ignored completely:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
        initializeData="MyApp.log"
        traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp" />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And then in the code:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Message", "Category")
```

In the MyApp.log:

```
Category: Message
```

Answer (score 7):

You've probably long figured this out, but `Trace.WriteLine()` ignores trace output options.  You need to use `Trace.TraceInformation()`, `.TraceError()`, or `.TraceWarning()`.  That may be what Tom was trying to say.

Internally, the trace listeners call `.TraceEvent()`, not `.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Trace.TraceInformation("Mass")`

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment then an answer.